# How to store number from string in python

Tags: python, string, numbers, store

i have string like this:

> string = "The stock item "28031 (111111: Test product)" was added successfully."

I need store from string the first 5 numbers ( for example "28031" ) and save them to another string.

It's because i am selenium tester and every time i am create new stock item he has different first 5 numbers.

Thank you for your help

Filip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = re.search("\d+", string)
print m.group(0)
```

prints 28031

It just selects the first group of digits, regardless of the length (2803 would be selected, too)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I am assuming all these strings have exactly the same format. If so the simplest way to get your stock item number is:

```
stocknumber = string.split()[3][1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

After sehe answer I leave mine edited just to show how to match 5 digits

```
import re
re.search('\d{5}', string).group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : neurino solution is the smartest!! use it

EDIT : sehe solution is smart and perfect you can add this line to get only the first 5 numbers:

```
print m.group(0)[0:5]
```

using [0:5] means to take string elements from 0 to 5 (first 5 elements)

---

use the [str.isdigit](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) built-in function

```
string = "The stock item 28031 "
Digitstring=''
for i in string:
    if i.isdigit():
        Digitstring+=i

print Digitstring
```

Output:

```
28031
```

you can count to first x numbers you need and then stop.